# WinRAR installer.rar situation (automating expect install)

Tags: bash, expect

I'm writing a script that should set up a server with no user input. Whatsoever.

In order to automate installation of some programs, I used expect. However, what can I use to automate `expect` instalation?

During the instalation user is prompted

```
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

and I want to automate the response (Y).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest approach is to use `yes`:

```
NAME
       yes - output a string repeatedly until killed

SYNOPSIS
       yes [STRING]...
       yes OPTION

DESCRIPTION
       Repeatedly output a line with all specified STRING(s), or 'y'.
```

In most cases, it is enough to run `yes | command` where `command` is whatever runs the installation.

Comment: "For more complex cases, you should check out expect." - You are a funny guy :D I'll check out yes command.

Comment: @Karlovsky120 not funny, just tired. I saw you had tagged with `expect` but failed to read that you actually used it. I was even wondering why you had tagged it since you hadn't used it. D'oh! :) Anyway, `yes` should do until you get `expect` ready. It's part of `coreutils` so it should be installed by default on any GNU system.